# How can I find all groups a user belongs to via DSQUERY

Tags: active-directory, scripting, ldap, dsquery

How can I find all groups for a specific user (groups for which the user is assigned) using [dsquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732952(WS.10).aspx)?

Comment: What does the below command does- dsget group <<"cn of group">>?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dsquery user -samid [username] | dsget user -memberof -expand | dsget group -samid
```

Good Luck!

Comment: -samid is apparently dark hidden knowledge. I've been looking for this for a long time. Thank you!